# I want to use same xml file with two different fragments

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm new to android programming. I want to write an android program which contains two fragments. Designs' will be same but I can't write layout file twice as it has a lot of widgets so is there a way to handle this?

If I copy xml file widget ids' stay same and I can't reach them in my java class...

Comment: Are you using the *exact* same XML layout in each fragment?

Comment: Why can't you inflate the same xml file in both the Fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you have fragment_container.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fraContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

What you need to do is to replace this container with one of the fragments in your program like this for example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_container);

    if (findViewById(R.id.fraContainer) != null) 
    {
        MyFragmentA myFragment = new MyFragmentA();        
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fraContainer, myFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

This will replace the fragment layout (container) with the fragment you want.

Now lets examine MyFragmentA, and MyFragmentB

```
public class MyFragmentA extends Fragment {

   ...

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_both, container, false);
      TextView x = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
      x.setText("I am fragment A");
      return view;
   }
   ...
```

And the second fragment

```
public class MyFragmentB extends Fragment {

   ...

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_both, container, false);
      TextView x = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
      x.setText("I am fragment B");
      return view;
   }
...
```

Both inflate the same fragment_both.xml, and both use the same TextView with the same ID, by referring to the view object!

I hope that helps you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the same xml file in more fragments, like this:

Fragment A

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

        ...

        return v;
    }
}
```

Fragment B

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

            ...

            return v;
        }
    }
```